# [Google Cloud][Compute Engine] Linux basics commands not found on startu-scripts

Tags: bash, ubuntu, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

I'm having trouble running a VM's startup scripts for instance groups. Commands like `touch`, `cat`, `chmod` are not found.

```
ubuntu@instance-template-****-1:~$ sudo google_metadata_script_runner -d --script-type startup
startup-script: INFO Starting startup scripts.
startup-script: INFO Found startup-script-url in metadata.
startup-script: INFO Downloading url from https://storage.googleapis.com/bucket-*****/startup-image to /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script using authentication token.
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 11: touch: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 12: touch: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 13: touch: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 15: chmod: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 16: chmod: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 71: ssh-keyscan: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 72: ssh-keygen: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 74: cat: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 76: git: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: /home/ubuntu/startup-scripts/script: line 78: sh: command not found
startup-script: INFO startup-script-url: Return code 127.
startup-script: INFO Finished running startup scripts.
```

Script:

```
#!/bin/bash

PATH=/home/ubuntu

cd $PATH

touch $PATH/.ssh/id_rsa
touch $PATH/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
touch $PATH/.ssh/known_hosts

chmod 644 $PATH/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
chmod 600 $PATH/.ssh/id_rsa

echo $IDRSA > $PATH/.ssh/id_rsa
echo $IDRSA_PUB > $PATH/.ssh/id_rsa.pub

ssh-keyscan bitbucket.org >> bitbucketKey
ssh-keygen -lf bitbucketKey

cat bitbucketKey >> $PATH/.ssh/known_hosts

git clone git@bitbucket.org:repo/repo.git

sh ./repo/prepare

PROJECT_ID=$(curl "http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/project/numeric-project-id" -H "Metadata-Flavor: Google")

./repo/deploy/run --dev --project-id=$PROJECT_ID
```

Comment: arg! This was an issue in the last week. you can't define `PATH` as you have done. `PATH` is the basic variable used to find all commands. Replace all references in your code to `$myHomePath` or similar, and you'll be much closer to a working system. When you do `echo $PATH`, you want to see something like `/usr/local/bin/:/usr/bin/:/bin:/usr/sbin`. Good luck.

Answer (score 3):

When you set `PATH=/home/ubuntu`, it overwrites the value of `PATH` environment variable that you're supposed to get in the shell and it forces the subsequent commands to end up in `"command not found"` error, because the appropriate executable files for running those commands are not available on new path `/home/ubuntu` that you just set. You can workaround this by renaming that variable to any name other than `PATH` and all of its occurrences in your script. You can use the same variable name in lower case too. (like `path=home/ubuntu`).

The `PATH` environment variable is a colon-delimited list of directories that your shell searches through when you enter a command. Program files (executables) are kept in many different places on the Unix system. Your path tells the Unix shell where to look on the system when you request a particular program.

Answer (score 2):

You modified the PATH environment in your script:

```
PATH=/home/ubuntu
```

However, PATH is a Shell Variables of bash:

```
PATH   The search path for commands.  It is a colon-separated list of directories in which the shell looks for commands (see
       COMMAND  EXECUTION below).  A zero-length (null) directory name in the value of PATH indicates the current directory.
       A null directory name may appear as two adjacent colons, or as an initial or trailing colon.   The  default  path  is
       system-dependent, and is set by the administrator who installs bash.  A common value is ``/usr/local/bin:
       /usr/local/sbin:/usr/bin:/usr/sbin:/bin:/sbin''.
```

Therefore almost all commands cannot be found. (Unless they are under /home/ubuntu)

---

If you just want to set a variable as a user folder to operate with the script, please change the variable name to like MY_HOME.

```
#!/bin/bash

MY_HOME=/home/ubuntu

cd $MY_HOME

touch $MY_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa
touch $MY_HOME/.ssh/id_rsa.pub
touch $MY_HOME/.ssh/known_hosts

...
```